# Run brew restart command using Homebrew module for Ansible

Tags: macos, ansible, homebrew, nagios, nagiosxi

I have been trying to run the command

`brew services restart nrpe`

with the help of Ansible's homebrew module.

I have gone through the documentation [(homebrew ansible doc)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/homebrew_module.html) but I couldn't find an example which does a similar thing. I have tried the following:

```
    - homebrew:
        name: nrpe
        state: present
        install_options: services,restart
```

but it didn't work. Please let me know the correct way to run the command 
`brew services restart nrpe`.

P.S. - Installation of `nrpe` or other services though homebrew is working great.

Edit 1 - Also including the Nagios tag because this might also be faced by the nagios community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [homebrew ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/homebrew_module.html), the command :

```
brew services restart nrpe
```

seems not implemented. The solution could be to use the [`command module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html):

```
- name: restart the nrpe service
  command: brew services restart nrpe
```

Comment: I tried this but I got this error. `fatal: [192.168.2.91]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "brew services restart nrpe", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}` . I have also tried other modules like `shell`, `script` etc. but none of them seem to work with the `brew` command.

Comment: Add full path to `brew`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Yes, I had tried with the full path and it worked.